# Add variable to an array only if it has a value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I am passing variable to my `index` view in Yii2 framework. I have the following code:

```
return $this->render('index', array(
    'userresult' => $userresult,
    'topresult' => $topresult,
    'result' => $result
));
```

I only need to pass variable `$userresult` if user is logged in since if user is not logged in, the `$userresult` variable does not exist. This is what I tried but I can not get the `if` statement to run:

```
return $this->render('index', array(
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) { echo "'userresult' => $userresult"; },
    'topresult' => $topresult,
    'result' => $result
));
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to do it:

```
// Initial array
$params = [
    'topresult' => $topresult,
    'result' => $result,
];

// Conditionally add other elements to array
if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $params['userresult'] = $userresult
}

return $this->render('index', $params);
```

Mixing `echo` with array is obviously wrong. You should learn more about arrays in plain PHP.

Also you can forget about `array()` syntax, use shorter variation `[]` since Yii2 requires PHP >= 5.4.

And I think it's better to pass `null` instead:

```
return $this->render('index', [
    'userresult' => $userresult ?: null,
    'topresult' => $topresult,
    'result' => $result
]);
```

Then you check if the variable is `null` or not, or just `if ($userresult) { ... }` in view. I think it's better then using `isset` in view. That way params number is constant.

Comment: Does this code go to my config or my current script?

Comment: In your current script. Also see suggested alternative.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it on my current script and it worked. You sir is a boss! Thanks for your help once again.